# Getting a short description of different towns programmatically, possibly from Wikipedia

Tags: api, wikipedia

Does anyone know an API or other method that I could generate a short description of various towns?

For instance, I'd like to put in `Bath`, and get something like:

> Bath ( /ˈbɑːθ/ or /ˈbæθ/) is a city in
>   the ceremonial county of Somerset in
>   the south west of England. It is
>   situated 97 miles (156 km) west of
>   London and 13 miles (21 km) south-east
>   of Bristol. The population of the city
>   is 83,992. It was granted city status
>   by Royal Charter by Queen Elizabeth I
>   in 1590, and was made a county borough
>   in 1889 which gave it administrative
>   independence from its county,
>   Somerset. The city became part of Avon
>   when that county was created in 1974.
>   Since 1996, when Avon was abolished,
>   Bath has been the principal centre of
>   the unitary authority of Bath and
>   North East Somerset (B&NES).

The content doesn't need to be anything special other than a brief bit of text about the place. If Wikipedia is the place to go, is there an existing API to access just the first paragraph or a summary of an article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wikipedia's API, you can fetch the wikitext of the "lead" section with [`prop=revisions`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv) (like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&titles=Bath,+Somerset)), or the HTML with [`action=parse`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse) (like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&page=Bath,+Somerset); note the HTML is encoded for embedding in the XML response, your XML parser should hand it to you properly decoded). Either way, though, you would have to filter out infoboxes and other templates.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: wikiUp is a jQuery plugin which allows you to display Wikipedia descriptions in tooltips.

http://functionn.blogspot.com/2012/11/wikiup-jquery-plugin-to-display.html